# problemas con soap y php

Tags: php, webservice, soap

Necesito llamar a una función en un **wsdl**, para lo cual estoy usando `__soapCall()` pero en el momento de usarlo me saca el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\producto.php:39 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('http://0.0.0.0:...', 'urn:georeferenc...', 1, 0) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\producto.php(39): SoapClient->__soapCall('georeferenciarC...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOAP\producto.php on line 39

Entiendo que también puedo usar `__doRequest()` pero los datos que me devuelve están en una cadena completa, es decir toda la información unida en una misma linea y sin espacio.

Lo que tengo en la `línea 39` es lo siguiente:

```
$vem = $cliente->__soapCall('georeferenciarCR',array($CodigoPais, $CodigoDepartamento, $CodigoMunicipio , $DireccionNatural , $Latitud , $Longitud));
```

Se que esos son los parametros que debo enviar porque esos son los parámetros implantados en el **xml**:

```
<soapenv:Header/>
           < soapenv:Body><br>
              < gis:WSGeorreferenciarCR-RQ><br>
                 < gis:CodigoPais>57</ gis:CodigoPais><br>
                 < gis:CodigoDepartamento>68</ gis:CodigoDepartamento><br>
                 < gis:CodigoMunicipio>68081000</ gis:CodigoMunicipio><br>
                 < gis:DireccionNatural>KR 19 # 65 - 15</ gis:DireccionNatural><br>
                 < !--Optional:--><br>
                 < gis:Latitud></gis:Latitud><br>
                 < !--Optional:--><br>
                 < gis:Longitud></gis:Longitud><br>
                 < gis:UNE_Cobertura_Especial>0</gis:UNE_Cobertura_Especial>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar y de antemano muchas gracias!

Código:

```
<?php
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
$wsdl = "http://10.00.00.00:8080/site/www/srvs/WSGeorreferenciarCRService?wsdl";
$xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:gis="http://www.une.net.co/gis">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
              <gis:WSGeorreferenciarCR-RQ>
                 <gis:CodigoPais>57</gis:CodigoPais>
                 <gis:CodigoDepartamento>68</gis:CodigoDepartamento>
                 <gis:CodigoMunicipio>68081000</gis:CodigoMunicipio>
                 <gis:DireccionNatural>KR 19 # 65 - 15</gis:DireccionNatural>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <gis:Latitud></gis:Latitud>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <gis:Longitud></gis:Longitud>
                 <gis:UNE_Cobertura_Especial>0</gis:UNE_Cobertura_Especial>
              </gis:WSGeorreferenciarCR-RQ>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>';   
$cliente = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
// $returndatos = $cliente->__doRequest($xml, $wsdl, 'urn:georeferenciarCR', null, 0);
// print_r($returndatos);

$parametros = array(
    "CodigoPais" => 57, 
    "CodigoDepartamento" => 68 , 
    "CodigoMunicipio" => 68081000, 
    "DireccionNatural" => "KR 19 # 65 - 15",
    "Latitud" => "",
    "Longitud" => "",
    "UNE_Cobertura_Especial" => 0);

$strResp = $cliente->__soapCall('georeferenciarCR',array($parametros));
var_dump($strResp);?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56799/discussion-on-question-by-originpntest-problemas-con-soap-y-php).

Answer (score -1):

```
$cliente= new SoapClient("http://url?wsdl",array('trace' => 1,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
$arreglo=array("CodigoPais"=>"valor1", "CodigoDepartamento"=>"valor2", "CodigoMunicipio"=>"valor3" , "DireccionNatural"=>"valor4" , "Latitud"=>"valor5" , "Longitud"=>"valor6");
$strResp = $cliente->__soapCall('georeferenciarCR',array($arreglo));
var_dump($strResp);
echo "Valor deseado(el nombre esta en el WSDL): \$strResp->conversionRateReturn = ". $strResp->conversionRateReturn. "<br/>";
$x=$strResp->conversionRateReturn;
echo "conversionRateReturn es un ejemplo tienes que ver la respuesta con var_dump e invocar lo que necesitas y guardarlo en una variable x o imprimirlo como necesites";
```

[image: codigo de ejemplo]

[image: ejecucion del codigo de ejemplo]

Comment: Hola men , gracias por responder. sin embargo el error aun esta ! cree un nuevo archivo con tu sintaxis pero aun no da !

Comment: <?php
 ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
 ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
    $wsdl = "http://IP:8080/xx/xx/xx/WSGeorreferenciarCRService?wsdl";
    $cliente = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace' => 1,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
    $vars = array(
     "CodigoPais" => 57, 
     "CodigoDepartamento" => 68 , 
     "CodigoMunicipio" => 68081000, 
     "DireccionNatural" => "KR 19 # 65 - 15",
     "Latitud" => "",
     "Longitud" => "",
        "UNE_Cobertura_Especial" => 0);
    $strResp = $cliente->__soapCall('georeferenciarCR',array($vars));
    var_dump($strResp);
?>

Comment: Como te comente arriba, el código que pones es insuficiente para darte una respuesta. ¿Como intentas leer la respuesta? Ese código no lo colocaste. ¿Que te imprime el var_dump cuando lo haces como en mi ejemplo?

Comment: no lo he colocado porque no me retorna nada ! en el comentario de arriba te coloque el codigo y como dije anteriormente ! solo me devuelve datos con __doRequest(), pero los datos me los devuelve todos unidos en una misma cadena de texto,  y no importa si lo imprimo con print_r, var_dump o un simple echo ! siempre me retorna el string junto . una de las maneras que encontre fue convertir ese string unido a un array, pero tengo el problema de que no siempre se encontrara el dato que necesito en la misma posicion y no siempre son los mismos caracteres en dicho item del array

Comment: y como te dije ! ni tu ejemplo ni el de nadie imprime nada ! ya que el error no es de impresion si no en el llamado ! si tengo el llamado en la linea 20 , ahi aparece el error y no en la 21 en donde esta el var_dump, print_r o el echo !

Comment: Es que ese es el asunto, si te imprime todo como html, esta bien invocado, pero la respuesta esta mal leída. Ya intentaste debugear con eclipse y xdebug, o con visual studio y php tools?? no se que IDE uses

Comment: Que error te sale en la linea 20??? que mensaje sale?? es el que pusiste en tu pregunta??

Comment: Si colocaste esta cadena tal cual:`IP:8080/xx/xx/xx/WSGeorreferenciarCRService?wsdl"` ese es el error te falta el http o https

Comment: no uso ningun ide en especifico ! uso sublime (politicas de la empresa)! y lo de la linea 20 es una suposición, lo que quiero decir es que si esta linea "$vem = $cliente->__call('georeferenciarCR',$parametros);" esta en la linea 20, y estoy imprimiendo $vem en la linea 21, php me dice que el error esta en la linea 20 no 21.. para que tengas idea de que error me refiero, revisa de nuevo la pregunta !

Comment: joder y obviamente no colocare la ip publica del srv al cual estoy haciendo el llamado -.-

Comment: si lo se pero el formato es asi `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8080/WSGeorreferenciarCRService?wsdl`, si ese formato esta bien, entonces creo que tienes problemas de permisos de red, no se si colocas esa url en tu navegador te conteste el wsdl??

Comment: Segun el error creo que esta mal tu url `__doRequest('http://0.0.0.0:...', 'urn:georeferenc...', 1, 0) #1 ` ya que la ip esta en ceros

Comment: brother, no es por ofender ! pero parece que hablara con alguien que trata de adivinar el problema y solo inventa a ver si da con la solucion !!

sin embargo ! acabo de publicar el codigo. y si lees la pregunta __doRequest() si me da ! solo que devuelve los datos de una manera que no me sirve! el wsdl si me funciona en el navegador y no son problemas con permisos de red.  de hecho si te fijas en el codigo que puse, no uso los textos directamente en el metodo sino que los guardo en una variable y luego los implemento, o simplemente notar que el codigo tiene un null en la version y el error no

Comment: Esta bien ya no te haré un comentario mas, por eso te puse unas imágenes de ejemplo, y si trate de adivinar ya que nunca me contestaste la pregunta ni con el código que pusiste al ultimo. ¿Como tratas de leer la respuesta? En otras palabras ¿Que va después de esto? `$strResp = $cliente->__soapCall('georeferenciarCR',array($parametros));
var_dump($strResp);`
Pero esta bien, no contestare mas.